# Configuring MapServer on Ubuntu with Apache

Tags: mapserver, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 /x64 / Apache2.

I wish to install MapServer on my system. The packages can be obtained from this place: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mapserver/7.2.0-5/+build/15292173 or by activating the proposed repository.

When I went to the MapServer website, it asks about compiling the whole thing. I found that it requires PHP5, whereas the 18.10 distribution provided PHP7. There are several inconsistencies in the documentation provided therein (i.e. MapServer website), and the actual packages. For example, the CMAKE utility asks for one libsvgcairo-dev, whereas I cannot locate any repository like that.

Overall the compilation fails.

If I install from the proposed distribution, I cannot find the php_mapscript.so, which is required for the Apache WebServer. Nor can I find any documentation related to launching the MapServer as a CGI.

I do not wish to use OSGEO Live.

Comment: Hopefully you have already managed to install and run MapServer but as a note for other readers, php_mapscript.so is certainly not required for the Apache WebServer.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu you can install using apt-get
Sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver mapserver-bin apache2

Comment: The question was regarding the configuration post installation of these packages.

Comment: I guess Im confused cause you are talking about compiling the mapserver. And so that is why I suggest the apt-get .  Also php is not really necessary for mapserver unless you use mapscript. I have been working on a document describing how to setup mapserver but I've not published it yet.  If you can give me more specifics of the installation steps you have done then that would be helpful.